# how to play swf file in standalone adobe flash player in html5

Tags: html, xml, flash

I have to play shockwave file in stand alone adobe flash player not in web browser and that shockwave file too contains xml file as content in it. all suggestions are welcomed please

Answer (score 0):

Google just launched a new Google Labs project called “Swiffy“. It converts Flash SWF files to HTML5.

It lets you reuse Flash content on devices without a Flash player (ie: iPhones and iPads).

sourced by : http://www.webpronews.com/convert-swf-files-to-html5-with-swiffy-2011-06

Comment: Thanx @Karthik but i have solved it by calling adobe flash player from command prompt and i have made one java program to fetch swf and xml file names from html file and then to call command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class ReadHtml implements Runnable {
    private static String flashFileName = "";
    private static String flashXmlName = "";
    private static String flashString = "";
    private static String flashPlayer = "flashplayer_11_sa";
    private static String htmlFilePath = "";

    public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("D:/.../index.html");
        Document doc = null;
        Element link = null;
        if (file.exists()) {
            htmlFilePath = file.getParent();
            doc = Jsoup.parse(file, "UTF-8", "");
            link = doc.select("embed").first();
        }
        flashXmlName = link.attr("flashvars");
        flashFileName = link.attr("src");
        flashString = flashFileName + "?" + flashXmlName;
        flashString = htmlFilePath + File.separator + flashString;

        Thread CmdThread = new Thread(new ReadHtml());
        CmdThread.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            final String[] cmdArray = { flashPlayer, flashString };
            final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```